# TeXstudio, highlights the errors on the wrong file

Tags: errors

I am a very new user of LateX and this might be a very trivial question but I don't really know how to solve it.
I am writing a thesis, and by suggestion of my tutor I have divided it into a 
 main file and the respective chapters that are latter inserted using function `\input{chapters\chapterX}`.
It happens that If I commit a mistake on line 5, for example on the chapter1.tex file, the line 5 of the main.tex is highlighted, even though there is nothing there.
I'll let you some images to illustrate my point.
[image: Line 164 presents an error because I've used unicode, but as you can see there's no formula on line 164 of my main file.]

[image: the error is actually here, but nothing is highlighted]

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please check that you have encoded all your tex code in utf-8.  Seems not be (see the several error messages you got for package inputenc) ... And pleasedo not show code as image, we can not copy and test on our own computers. So please do not show code snippets, make a short complete compilable tex code resulting in your issue ...

Comment: I am having the same issue. In my main document there are lines highlighted which are entirely commented out. The issues reported actually are referring to an included document (with \input{xy})